# Windows 10 bottom right corner primary click doesn't work after unchecking "Enable Secondary Corner Click"

Tags: windows-10, context-menu, synaptics-touchpad

I'm on a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro using [the Windows 10 19.0.9.5 touchpad drivers](http://support.lenovo.com/bd/bn/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-2-pro-lenovo/downloads/DS103340), which apparently are identical to [the latest Windows 10 touchpad drivers available on the Lenovo website](http://www.synaptics.com/en/drivers.php). Since this touchpad, like all newer "Microsoft" touchpads, don't have true buttons, I disabled secondary corner click, relying on two finger click for context menu only, which I find more predictable.

Unfortunately, disabling this option in the touchpad settings doesn't restore normal clicking functionality to the bottom right corner. Instead it just becomes a dead corner in terms of clicking; single finger clicks don't do anything when done in the bottom right corner.

I've messed around quite a bit in the hell that is the Windows registry to try to enable click functionality, but to no avail. I've also tried the drivers from both the Lenovo and Synaptics websites. I'm hoping some of you all have been able to figure out some workaround until Synaptic decides to actually issue a patch for the numerous bugs their Windows 10 drivers have.